# Calculation of integral using basic techniques

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> If the value of integral $\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{4x^3(1+x^{8020})}{1+x^{8048}}dx$ is $\frac{p}{q}$ where $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime positive integer then find the ten's digit of $q$.

I agree this is somewhat a homework question but I just want a hint or trick for approach.

---

My attempt:

I tried separating the two terms in numerator and put
$\ x^{4}=t$, so first integral was reduced to $\frac{{dt}}{1+x^{2012}}$. Then I got struck as no substitution was working for the second part.

Comment: Can you please tell which site you got this question from? This integral is astoundingly close to $1$ by the look of things.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon ya its 1 , the question is from one of the competitive exams(jee)

Comment: Which year of JEE? (I know 2020 just happened) I want to find the paper online. This one looks like a typo to me.

Comment: I somewhat agree with @TeresaLisbon. I had solved a similar question of JEE Adv. It was $$\int_0^1 \frac{4x^3(1+x^{8040})}{(1+x^4)^{2012}}dx$$

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I copied directly from a site . What I think is it could be solved by integration inequalities

Comment: Ok, which site is this? I still think there's a problem with the question, so you need to show me the site, tell me a way to get into the test etc. Integration inequalities are of no help if it is asking for the *value* of the integral, which I assume requires identity based computations, not inequality. From numericals, your integral is very close to $1$, while @SarGe's is $4.9 \times 10^{-4}$.

Comment: How did you reduce it to $\frac{{dt}}{1+x^{2012}}$ may I ask?

Comment: @DatBoi I didn't reduce I tried to separate it into two integrals but that didnt help

Comment: Ok I logged in. Which test do I take?

Comment: Yes can you do that?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon done

Comment: That question is off by *miles*, as the answers show, so it was probably a typo Anusha. @SarGe Did you solve yours using the substitution $x \to x^4$, because Wolfram shows that even this one has some odd looking answer.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon, my answer is $\frac{1}{2011}$.

Comment: @Anusha The comparison with SarGe's question shows that your question is way off the mark in terms of what it should have been. You can go home relaxed, you are not having this kind of razzmatazz in the JEE exam anytime.

Comment: @SarGe how did you solve yours pls tell me in chat

Comment: @Anusha, [here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdjGR.jpg) my solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Letting $u=x^4$, gives $\mathrm du=4x^3\mathrm dx$. Note that $2012=503\times 4$ and $2005=401\times 5$, nothing special about these numbers, except that $401, 503$ are prime, but that doesn't seem to be of any use here. $$\begin{aligned}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1+u^{2005}}{1+u^{2012}}\mathrm du =\int_{0}^{1}(1+u^{2005})\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{r}u^{2012r}\mathrm du\end{aligned}\\ = \sum_{r=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{r}\left(\frac{1}{2012r+1}+\frac{1}{2012r+2006}\right) $$

The expression is very close to $1$, but I don't know if it can be written in the form as required in the question.

Answer (score 3):

$$I=\int_0^1\frac{4x^3(1+x^{8020})}{1+x^{8048}}dx$$

$$I=\int_0^1\frac{1+t^{2005}}{1+t^{2012}}dt$$

$$\int_0^1 \frac{(1+t^{2012})^2}{1+t^{2012}}dt > I > \int_0^1 \frac{1+t^{2012}}{1+t^{2012}}dt$$

$$\int_0^1 1dt +\int_0^1 t^{2012} dt > I > 1$$

$$1 +\frac{1}{2013} > I > 1$$

$$1.00049677099> I > 1$$

which is a naive bound for the integral

(considering the fact that the question likely has an erratum)

Comment: How did you write the 3rd step

Comment: @Anusha Note that $r^2<r, r \in (0,1)$ and $r^2>r, r \in (1,\infty)$

Answer (score 3):

There must be a problem somewhere since, after $x=t^4$, the general case
$$\int_0^1 \frac {1+t^a}{1+t^b}\,dt=\frac{\psi \left(\frac{a+b+1}{2 b}\right)+\psi \left(\frac{b+1}{2 b}\right)-\psi \left(\frac{a+1}{2 b}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{1}{2 b}\right) } {2b}$$ Applied to your case where $a=b-7$ this gives,
$$\frac{\psi \left(\frac{b+1}{2 b}\right)+\psi \left(\frac{b-3}{b}\right)-\psi \left(\frac{b-6}{2b}\right)-\psi \left(\frac{1}{2
   b}\right) }{2b} $$ this means that the result would involve trigonometric functions of angles multiples of $\frac \pi {4024}$.

Expanded as series for large values of $b$ , this gives for the integral
$$1+\frac{7 \pi ^2}{12 b^2}-\frac{35 \left(\psi ^{(2)}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\psi
   ^{(2)}(1)\right)}{16 b^3}+\frac{1519 \pi ^4}{720 b^4}-\frac{1295 \left(\psi
   ^{(4)}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\psi ^{(4)}(1)\right)}{768 b^5}+$$ $$\frac{34441 \pi
   ^6}{4320 b^6}-\frac{9331 \left(\psi ^{(6)}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\psi ^{(6)}(1)\right)}{18432
   b^7}+O\left(\frac{1}{b^8}\right)$$ and for $b=2012$ the truncated value
$$1+\frac{7 \pi ^2}{48577728}+\frac{1519 \pi ^4}{11798978288209920}+\frac{34441 \pi
   ^6}{286583778981283550330880}$$ $$-\frac{35 \left(\psi ^{(2)}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\psi
   ^{(2)}(1)\right)}{130317851648}-\frac{1295 \left(\psi ^{(4)}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\psi
   ^{(4)}(1)\right)}{25322180603603582976}-\frac{9331 \left(\psi ^{(6)}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\psi
   ^{(6)}(1)\right)}{2460188003457461347267117056}$$ which is
$$1.000001426086387731117817$$ while the exact value is
$$1.000001426086387731118859$$